# How to put div elements side by side?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying all day to get the "nav" and "body" divs to sit side by side, but it seems like i'm locked to the width of the nav-bar somehow. I can't for the life of me get them to float next to each other, they only stack...
more specifically, i'm trying to put the body div in the middle of the view port, any ideas?
thanks in advance for any help!

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<HTML lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href="stylesheeet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url("back.gif");
      background-color: #c0c0c0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    #nav {
      padding: 1%;
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
    
    .navbutton {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #d0d0d0;
      color: #4040c0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    a {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #slogan {
      padding-top: 0;
      padding-bottom: 1%;
      padding-left: .5%;
    }
    
    #logo {}
    
    #body {}
    
    .outline {
      text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
    }
    
    #main {}
  </style>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div text-align="center" id="logo">
    <A id="logo" HREF="">
      <IMG SRC="" border="0">
    </A><br>
    <font face="impact" color="yellow" size="6">
      <div id="slogan">
        <p1 class="outline"></font>
    </p1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="nav" align="left">
      <table id="navtab" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
        <tr align=left valign=top>
          <td width=120>
            <center>
              <table width=120 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
                <tr align=center valign=top>
                  <td>
                    <a class="navlink" id="side1" href=""><button class="navbutton" style="float: left;"></button></a><br>
                    <a class="navlink" id="side2" href=""><button class="navbutton" style="float: left;">About Us</button></a><br>
                    <a class="navlink" id="side3" href=""><button class="navbutton" style="float: left;">Content list</button></a><br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <a class="navlink" id="side4" href="">© 19-2018 </a><br>
                    <font face=arial size=1>
                      <a class="navlink" href=</a><br>
                  </td>
              </table>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
      <font face="impact" color="yellow" size="6">
        <p1 class="outline"></font>
      </p1>
      <br>
      <br>
      <font face="impact" color="black" size="4">
        <p1><a href="article.html">here</a> to find out! </font>
      </p1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is your goal to have a side navigation bar?

Comment: that would be ideal, yes

Comment: Don't any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=divs+side+by+side) answer your question?

Comment: I've been looking at the other answers, but none of them seem to work here... I don't know why... I was just looking for some other advise

Comment: Note that the HTML is invalid: there is no `p1` element, the `font` tag has been deprecated since HTML 4, as has the `center` tag. Also, the tags are not nested properly.

Comment: Yeah, it needs a lot of work, this website has been dead since 2012, I'm trying to breathe some new life into it and update it a bit, I just got hung up on trying to get the divs in the right place

Answer (score 1):

Use flex-box to overcome this problem 
first set display:flex and flex:row on the parent element that contains both the div and navbar then use flex numbers on child elements like flex:1 or flex:2 the highest number flex occupies maximum available space.

Comment: that still didn't put them next to each other... any other ideas?